# Compare if one tuple is greater when mixing `str` and `None` types in Python

Tags: python, tuples, comparison

I have two lists of tuples that have a mix of `str` and `None` types and need to compare them considering `None` to be greater.

```
a = tuple([None, 4])
b = tuple(['pencil', 12])

a > b
```

Results in:

> TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'str'

How can I compare these items without getting that error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also subclass `tuple` and create your own tuple class with the `__lt__` and `__gt__` methods appropriately implemented:

```
class MyTuple(tuple):
    def __lt__(self, other):
        for s, o in zip(self, other):
            if s == o:
                continue
            if s is None:
                return False
            if o is None:
                return True
        return super().__lt__(other)

    def __gt__(self, other):
        return not self.__lt__(other)


a = MyTuple([None, 4])
b = MyTuple(['pencil', 12])

print(a < b) # False
print(a > b) # True
```

Comment: Gotcha, I like that use of super to fall back on.

Comment: My only question with doing it this way is that I think it'd loop through the tuple an extra time when there isn't a `None` value.

Comment: That is correct. However, you're doing the same thing in your approach as well (`item1 > item2` in the `try` block) for the case where there *is* a `None` present.

Comment: Good point! It depends on the use case (whether None is likely to be present). I think I'll end up putting the `return super().__lt__(other)` in a try-except block for my use case.

Comment: The implementation of `__gt__` is incorrect. It will return True when the tuples are equal (e.g. `print(a > a) # True`)

Answer (score 0):

You can replace `item > item2` with a function like this:

```
def compare_tuples(item1, item2):
    try:
        return item1 > item2
        # if they can be compared, just do so directly
    except TypeError:
        for field1, field2 in zip(item1, item2):
            # otherwise go through the fields in the tuples 
            # and compare them checking if they are none
            if field1 == field2:
                continue
            if field1 is None:
                return True
            if field2 is None:
                return False
```